# Get APIs from binance with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am getting APIs from binance for crypto assets and to get that im writing for every asset a new line of code, i want to know how can i get api for all assets with a simple method with foreach in PHP.

Here is how im getting the APIs from binance now.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker?symbol=BTCUSDT");
$obj = json_decode($json);

$price = $obj->bidPrice;

$sql="UPDATE `open_trades` SET `live_price` = '$price' WHERE `asset` = 'Bitcoin';";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();

$sql="UPDATE `assets` SET `price` = '$price'  WHERE `name` = 'Bitcoin';";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
```

I need to get with foreach function, i have the assets table on database where i declare the symbol for example bitcoin i have "BTCUSDT", i want to use a method get all from a foreach function just get the symbols from database.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You should select all coins from assets where I suppose you have a column named `symbol` and one named `cryptoname` with values like: BTCUSDT, etc. and Bitcoin

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `assets`";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$result = $result->fetchAll()

foreach ($result as $key => $row) ) {
    $json = file_get_contents("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker?symbol=" . $row["symbol"]);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $price = $obj->bidPrice;

    $sql="UPDATE `open_trades` SET `live_price` = '$price' WHERE `asset` = '" . $row["cryptoname"] . "';";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();

    $sql="UPDATE `assets` SET `price` = '$price'  WHERE `name` = '" . $row["cryptoname"] . "';";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for answering, im doing as you said, but im geting a error like this 

`Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_array()`

Comment: Also when i changed the `while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))` to this  `while ($row = $result->fetch())` it is updating me only one row on database.

Comment: Now I noticed is PDO, I modified the answer with $result->fetchAll()
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Mate i'm so sorry, but it is still not working for me, i feel bad asking but its throwing me a error `Undefined variable: result` and `Call to a member function execute()` i'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry, long time since I didn't write PDO / Vanilla queries without a framework. I edited the answer.

Comment: I'm still geting a error `Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool` im not that good in this PHP.

Comment: Please check the whole answer again. fetchAll() is outside the loop and the iteration is done with a foreach now.

Comment: Dude thank you soo much, i really appreciate it. I really thank you that there is still people like you alive. Thanks Mate.

Comment: No problem mate! If my answer was correct, please mark it as solved. Thx!